# doc.fromHTML is not a function with angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, jspdf, export-to-pdf

I wanna export a template html to pdf and I'm trying use jsPDF lib with angular, but o got this error doc.fromHTML is not a function.

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
// declare var jsPDF: any;
@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
title = 'exports-pdf';
@ViewChild('exports') exports: ElementRef;

public print(): void {

const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');

const content = this.exports.nativeElement;

const margins = {
  top: 80,
  bottom: 60,
  left: 40,
  width: 522
};
console.log(doc);
setTimeout(() => {
  doc.fromHTML(content.innerHTML, margins.left, margins.top, {}, function() {
    doc.output('export.pdf');
  }, margins);
  }, 100);
 }
}
```

I tried too to use `import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf'; or declare var jsPDF: any;`

when I use `declare var jsPDF: any`, I have at the console all jsPDF properties, but nothing happen when I click on button. When I  use `import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf'` i have an object without any properties like this image:
[image: object without any properties]

In angular.json i put in scripts the imports

`"scripts": [
   "./node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js",
   "./node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.debug.js"
 ]`

and the error goes on.

I found other dudes with the same error but without solution. I don't know if it is a lib bug or if with angular it not work very well.

I uploaded the code to [GitHub](https://github.com/marcelojunin/exports_pdf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove what I commented from your code. To export as pdf you need to use `save function` `doc.save("export.pdf");`

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
// import { log } from 'util'; ** REMOVE **
// import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf'; ** REMOVE **
declare var jsPDF: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'exports-pdf';
  @ViewChild('exports') exports: ElementRef;

  public print(): void {

    const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');

    const content = this.exports.nativeElement;

    const margins = {
      top: 80,
      bottom: 60,
      left: 40,
      width: 522
    };
    console.log(doc);
 //   setTimeout(() => { ** REMOVE **
      doc.fromHTML(content.innerHTML, margins.left, margins.top, {}, function () {
      //  doc.output('export.pdf'); ** REMOVE **
        doc.save("export.pdf");
      }, margins);
 //   }, 100); ** REMOVE **
  }
}
```

**angular.json**

```
"scripts": [
   "./node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js",
 //  "./node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.debug.js" ** REMOVE **
 ]
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ExportsPdf</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<!-- ** REMOVE ** <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.debug.js"></script> -->
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, man. I tried use the save() but i was importing this import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
I was already hopeless. Thank you again!

Comment: says `jsPDF` is not defined in console. can you please help me out? I'm having similar issues using Angular 10

Comment: Have you this line `declare var jsPDF: any;`?

Comment: I'm getting the same error.' jsPDF is not defined', any solution ?

Comment: unable to get pdf

Comment: `import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";` if it says jsPDF is not defined

Comment: @ferhado Getting `doc.fromHTML is not a function` error when I use `import { jsPDF } from 'jspdf';` OR `declare var jsPDF: any;` in Angular 10

Comment: @Pinaki have you imported this script `./node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js` ?

Comment: @ferhado getting `jsPDF is not defined` error in browser after doing all 4 steps, 1. declare var jsPDF: any; in .ts, 2. angular.json - "architect" : {... "build": {..."options": {"scripts": ["./node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js"]}}, 3. "dependencies": { "@angular/core": "~10.1.3", "jspdf": "^2.3.0", }

Comment: @Pinaki , Please make an example on https://stackblitz.com

Comment: @ferhado https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6gwogv , open console & click on button.

Comment: @Pinaki Also the problem is that js fie not imported, alternative you can remove it from angular.json and package.json and put this script in you index.html
`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.debug.js"></script>`