# I cannot use jsPDF with Angular 10

Tags: angular, jspdf

I was trying to print my page using `jspdf` library. I've tried so many solutions to get it done following examples on here and almost every Google suggestion links but I still couldn't fix it.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
.....
openPDF(): void {
    const DATA = this.couponPage.nativeElement;
    const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
    doc.fromHTML(DATA.innerHTML, 15, 15);
    doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');
}
```

Trying to import `jsPDF` like the above creates the following error while compiling

> ERROR in src/...component.ts:42:21 - error
> TS2351: This expression is not constructable.
> Type 'typeof import("jspdf")' has no construct signatures.
>
> ```
> 42     const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
> ```

So, I've tried to import it in another way as suggested in this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53972965/6810539)

```
declare var jsPDF: any;
```

And yet this creates a console error saying that `jsPDF` is not defined.

Then I found another solution as posted in here [Angular 10/9/8 PDF Tutorial – Export PDF in Angular with JSPDF](https://www.positronx.io/angular-pdf-tutorial-export-pdf-in-angular-with-jspdf/)

And following this method now I got the following error

> ERROR TypeError: doc.fromHTML is not a function
> openPDF notice.component.ts:43
> ...Component_Template_button_click_2_listener ...component.html:3
> Angular 23

I've no Idea what I've missed here as this library supposed to work in all Angular versions. Any help will be appreciated.

Here I've created a [Stackblitz project](https://angular-ivy-vtuj3b.stackblitz.io)

Comment: You could refer here for a Stackblitz of how to import `jsPDF`: https://stackblitz.com/edit/jspdf-fpmqwp

Comment: Hav eyou add    `"./node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js",` in the  scripts in angular.json ? otherwise `declare var...`wont suceed

Comment: @CharybdeBE Yes I did include in `angular.json`

Comment: @MichaelD it's not working still throwing a console error of `doc.fromHTML is not a function`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After trying so many different solutions for this issue now I've found that both the `addHTML` and `fromHTML` is depreciated in latest versions of `jspdf` and they are replaced with just `html`. For those who are seeking for a better solution to work with `jspdf` and `Angular 10` here is what looks working and a better result that I've found so far.

To import `jspdf` version (2.x.x), just simply do: `import { jsPDF } from 'jspdf';`.

You won't need to include any of the dependencies into `angular.json` scripts like you would do in previous versions. And if you add scripts of `jspdf` or `html2canvas` inside`index.html`, also remove them. By running `npm install jspdf` it also install the `html2canvas` which is also dynamically imported by `jspdf`.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { jsPDF } from 'jspdf';

.....

 @ViewChild('couponPage', { static: true }) couponPage: ElementRef;

.......

openPDF(): void {
  const DATA = this.couponPage.nativeElement;
  const doc: jsPDF = new jsPDF("p", "mm", "a4");
  doc.html(DATA, {
     callback: (doc) => {
       doc.output("dataurlnewwindow");
     }
  });
}
```

> Though for me still using `doc.html()` method, it wouldn't use the
> `css` style that I used for my page.

Comment: When I tried in the way you have explained, I get `core.js:6162 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined` .  Did you see this error in your implementation ?

Answer (score 3):

After working with the OP for a short time on a stackblitz, it seems the main problem was that the usage of the library changed between versions 1.3.5 (the one used in the examples) to 2.1.0 (the one he was using). I am adding this answer so that it may provide a clue to future solution seekers who suffer from a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the import directive you are using, try

```
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';
```

Note that if you are using this method, you will have to delete the

```
declare var jsPDF:any;
```

Comment: What is the error message you get when you use that particular import directive?

Comment: when I use the `declare` method, it says `jsPDF` is not defined while compiling. And when I import it as you did on your answer I got `doc.fromHTML is not a function` error in browser console.

Comment: So the switching import statements moved the problem from compile time to run time. Are you sure you deleted the declare statement? Also, what is the line you use to instantiate doc variable? (the one which contains doc=new jsPDF(....))

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure I've deleted the declare statement while importing `jspdf`. And this is how I instantiate doc varaiable `const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');` I don't know what I did wrong here.

Comment: In the jsPDF documentation, that is not how they use the constructor. Try let doc=new jsPDF(); and see if the error changes.

Comment: I've tried that as well, same error. Even following the documentation itself, the `addHTML` and `fromHTML` throws not a function error in console. This thing is giving me a headache. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220733/discussion-between-boluc-papuccuoglu-and-kirubel).

Answer (score 0):

I just ran "npm install jspdf" in my project directory and it worked for me.