# Property 'fromHTML' does not exist on type jsPDF

Tags: javascript, angular, jspdf

I am trying to use jsPDF to convert an HTML code to PDF. I've seen that the best way to do this is to use the jsPDF.fromHTML() function but when I try I get the following:

> Property 'fromHTML' does not exist on type 'jsPDF'

I am using Angular 10 and jsPDF@2.3.0.
I already tried to `npm i jspdf` again and to rollback to version 2.2.0 but with no luck

Comment: Whats the question? Convert or "Downgrade"?

Comment: Convert. I've seen that I can create an image and basically add it to the pdf with html2canvas or use the fromHTML() function which does not seem to exist in the current version. There is an html() function but I'm not quite sure it does exactly the same thing as fromHTML()

Comment: this will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63684298/11903143